# How to automatically convert AWS types to JSON

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Working with AWS DynamoDB, its necessary to pack and unpack data into the AWS type format ([attribute value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html)).

**Question:** Is there an automated way to do this **in python**?
Im looking for a function that takes a json as input and returns a json with the correct attribute values, and vice versa.

Example: 
The below json is correct formmatted for AWS dynamodb:

```
"NewImage": {
    "city": {
      "S": "Copenhagen"
    },
    "project_id": {
      "N": "4203"
    },
    "district": {
      "N": "4"
    },
    "floor": {
      "NULL": true
    },
    "country": {
      "S": "Denmark"
    },
    "accountManager": {
      "N": "2"
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
"NewImage": {
    "city": "Copenhagen",
    "project_id": 4203,
    "district": 4,
    "floor": null,
    "country": "Denmark",
    "accountManager": 2,
}
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903479/python-lambda-function-parsing-dynamodbs-json-format

Comment: Just use boto3; there is no longer needed to use your own conversion

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that? I am using boto3