# Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

> Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Object of type 'Decimal' is not JSON serializable

I went through all the existing solutions in the following link but nothing worked for me. What am I doing wrong?:
[Python JSON serialize a Decimal object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960516/python-json-serialize-a-decimal-object)

```
import json
import boto3
import decimal


client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table('table')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    method = event["httpMethod"]
    print(event)
    if method=="POST":
        return POST(event)
    elif method=="DELETE":
        return DELETE(event)
    elif method=="GET":
        return GET(event)

#the respons format
def send_respons(responseBody, statusCode):
    response = {
        "statusCode": statusCode,
        "headers": {
            "my_header": "my_value"
        },
        "body": json.dumps(responseBody),
        "isBase64Encoded": 'false'
    }
    return response
    

def GET(event):
    tab = table.scan()['Items']
    ids = []
            for item in tab:
                    ids.append({"id":item["id"], "decimalOBJ":decimal.Decimal(item["decimalOBJ"]}))
            return send_respons(ids, 201)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems you have two options:

1. Probably easiest, you can serialize the int/float value of a Decimal object:

`""" assume d is your decimal object """`

`serializable_d = int(d) # or float(d)`

`d_json = json.dumps(d)`

2. You can add [simplejson](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to your requirements.txt, which now has support for serializing Decimals. It's a drop-in replacement for the included json module.

> ```
> import simplejson as json # instead of import json
> ```

The rest of your code will work the same. If you need further assistance, kindly leave a comment.

Comment: Decimal objects exist specifically for accuracy; casting to float has the potential to add uncertainty. I'd go with a string value before converting a Decimal to another type.

Comment: True, and the json serialization automatically converts the value to a string. But fair point, nonetheless.

Comment: If you know it is precise to cents, you can exactly send it to js by scaling it up by 100 as a decimal, then truncate to bigint, as long as you stay <= +/- 2**53, it will be perfectly exact for integers when js puts it in a double. Then divide by 100 and `.toFixed(2)` at the last moment in js and it'll work as intended.

Comment: then the next Exception: <class 'TypeError'>: Object of type date is not JSON serializable.

Comment: option 2 only.
I don't recommend Option 1 at all.

Answer (score 29):

Here is an example of extending the `JSONEncoder` to handle `Decimal` type also specified in the [json docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder)

```
from decimal import Decimal

class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
      return str(obj)
    return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

Call it using

```
json.dumps(some_object, cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

By converting to a `str` a good degree of precision will be maintained, without relying on external packages.

Comment: You might want to try `return str(obj.normalize())` instead. See https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize for details on decimal normalization.

Answer (score 5):

Create a function to handle the `TypeError` and use `default` argument of `json.dumps` to set this. This avoid `TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

> If specified, default should be a function that gets called for
> objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON
> encodable version of the object or raise a TypeError. If not
> specified, TypeError is raised.

***json_utils.py:***

```
import decimal
import json


def dumps(item: dict) -> str:
    return json.dumps(item, default=default_type_error_handler)


def default_type_error_handler(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, decimal.Decimal):
        return int(obj)
    raise TypeError
```

***test_json_utils.py:***

```
import json
from decimal import Decimal
from commons import json_utils


def test_different_data_types():
    # Prepare data
    item = {
        "a-string": "lorem",
        "a-boolean": True,
        "a-number": 4711,
        "a-decimal-object": Decimal(4711)  # Used by dynamoDb boto3 client
    }

    # Execute
    item_as_json = json_utils.dumps(item)

    # Assert
    item_back_to_dict = json.loads(item_as_json)
    assert item_back_to_dict == item
```